# Fastify multiple method in a route?

Tags: fastify

In **express**, I can do something like this:

```
router.route("/").get(getController).post(postController)
```

How can **fastify** also do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastify does not have this chaining option, you can use multiple methods with one handler: [`fastify.route()`](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Routes/#full-declaration)

```js
fastify.route({
  url: '/',
  method: ['GET', 'POST'],
  handler: singleController
})

// or
fastify.get('/', getController).post('/', postController)
```